# Speed up the jquery ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I have a game site with some grids. More than one player can play the same game at a time.

If any user clicks a single grid, i need to convert that particular grid to active state for all the user those who are playing the game now. For that, i made the ajax call for every seconds to make the selected grids active. But it slows the process, since it access the database for every time.

Please help me to do this task in any other way without slow

Comment: I think what you might want to consider is having a socket connection open to deal with these "real time" updates... That many AJAX requests will most certainly slow things down.

Comment: have a look at signalr library,its what you need

Answer (score 0):

Use WebSocket in that case and you don't need a database.
With WebSocket you can easily push data to all your connected clients in realtime.
And you have the nice ability to push new data directly from server to client. 
The client doesn't need to send every x second a call to the server. There is a persistent connection.

A good WebSocket Library written in PHP you can find here: http://socketo.me